# Sharepoint 2013 User Profile Service, will delete a user profile from SP cause deletion on AD?

Tags: user-profile-service, active-directory-import

I setup a User Profile Service using SharePoint Profile Synchronization Option. And have imported few hundred of AD users to the SharePoint.

Since there are some service account imported to SharePoint so I deleted it on the SharePoint User Profile page. Now I worry, will it also delete the account in AD?

Comment: No it won't... Don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting User Profiles in SharePoint won't delete account in the active directory. You can verify that by opening "Active Directory Users and Computers" on your local PC and search for that service account you deleted the User Profile for.

Comment: So I have another question. Since the AD is managed by another team, we don't want the SharePoint will affect any property of AD account.

Comment: I learnt from document, the SharePoint Profile synchronization provide bi-directional sync between SP and AD. Does it mean that if I change some property of a user profile, it will get updated to AD as well?

Comment: You have to configure fields in the Active Directory, to receive data from SharePoint. For Example the User Profile Picture. This can be a field in the AD where it gets the picture from SharePoint. Otherwise SharePoint can't make direct changes to the Active Directory.

Comment: You also need the permission to make changes to objects in AD. Without this, even if you configure export, it won't make any changes.